# How do I use std::num::sqrt to compute the square root of a number?

Tags: rust

I want to take the square root of a number.

I looked at the documentation [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.10/std/num/fn.sqrt.html), and wrote `use std::num;` at the top of my program which I thought would have allowed me to `sqrt`. This doesn't work though, so what do I need to do to actually use `std::num::sqrt`?

```
let upperLimit: i64 = sqrt(num as f64) + 1; //doesnt work
```

I'm very new to Rust coming from c++, so I really don't understand that real use of `use`.

Comment: Are you meaning to be using Rust 0.10? (The current latest version is 0.11, but using the [nightlies](http://www.rust-lang.org/install.html) is recommended.)

Comment: @dbaupp that may be my problem then, Arjan's answer still does not work for me. I must still be using .10

Comment: the freestanding `std::num::sqrt` function *only* exists in 0.10; if you're using master/nightly you should be [using the appropriate docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/?search=sqrt).

Answer (score 84):

Since Rust 1.0, the following should be used:

```
let upperLimit = (number as f64).sqrt() as i64 + 1;
```

Or, equivalently:

```
let upperLimit = f64::sqrt(number) as i64 + 1;
```

See the docs for [`f64::sqrt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.sqrt).

Answer (score 12):

> **Editor's Note:** This historical answer predates Rust 1.0 and is no longer applicable.

With `use std::num;` you "import" the whole module and access members with `num::*`:

```
use std::num;

let upperLimit: i64 = num::sqrt(num as f64) + 1;
```

If you want to use `sqrt` directly you have to import it as `use std::num::sqrt;`:

```
use std::num::sqrt;

let upperLimit: i64 = sqrt(num as f64) + 1;
```

Comment: A small note, the first is considered better style.

Comment: this answer doesn't seem to be working for me. I even made sure to reinstall the nightly build to get the most updated version of rust. I just receive `unresolved name 'num::sqrt'` even though I included `use std::num;`

Comment: @SyntacticFructose `sqrt` is now a method `(num as f64).sqrt()`.